# couchdb windows kernel-poll not supported; "K" parameter ignored

Tags: couchdb

I installed couchdb from the binaries at http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/install/windows.html on Windows 7 [Version 6.1.7601]

When I try to start it from the command line

```
c:\CouchDB\bin>couchdb
```

I get the message

`kernel-poll not supported; "K" parameter ignored.`

and there's a Windows alert that erl.exe has stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the result of running CouchDB as an unprivileged user in Windows. [This post](http://www.pastbedti.me/2009/04/running-couchdb-under-an-unprivileged-user-account/) suggests configuring CouchDB to use unprivileged directories:

```
[couchdb]
database_dir = ./couchdb
view_index_dir = ./couchdb
```

Another solution might be just to run as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Tried it, doesn't work.

In the end I installed pouchdb, which functions as a drop-in replacement for the old, red, cum stained sofa.  Worked right out of the box.

Comment: But I would still like someone to install on their Windows 7 machine and see whether they get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your installation path doesn't contain any space

instead of

```
C:/Program Files/Apache CouchDB
```

it should be

```
C:/CouchDB
```